# How to have batch script wait for free licence before executing?

Tags: scripting

Is there any way to make a mathematica script (that I'm running in batch using HTCondor) wait until there is an available licence before executing? Several of my scripts are returning nothing but error messages reporting that the licence limit for my institution has been reached...